# oracle package and trigger

Tags: oracle, triggers, plsql-package

Create a database that contains four tables department, employee,
address and contact info, then Store 5 Records in each table.
Write the PL/SQL Statement for the following:

1. Store a record into employee, address and contact using trigger.
2. Retrieve departments and their employees using package

..........................

this is my code , what am i doing wrong ?

```
-- Question 2  :
-- Create Tables :
CREATE TABLE address (
code int primary key,
city varchar2(30),
street varchar2(30)
);
create table Department (
DepId int primary key ,
Dep_Name varchar2(30) ,
Dep_adress varchar(30));
create table Employee (
Emp_Id int primary key ,
firstName varchar2(30),
lastName varchar2(30),
salary int,
Dep_Id int references Department (DepId),
AdCode int references address (code));
CREATE TABLE contact_info (
email varchar2(30) primary key ,
phone int ,
EmpId int references Employee (Emp_Id));
-- insert   :
insert into Department values (1,'IT','Amman');
insert into Department values (2,'CS','Jerash');
insert into Department values (3,'accounting','Amman');
insert into Department values (4,'managment','Amman');
insert into Department values (5,'employment','Amman');
insert into address values (50,'Amman','AAA');
insert into address values (60,'Amman','AAB');
insert into address values (70,'Amman','AAC');
insert into address values (80,'Jerash','AAD');
insert into address values (90,'Irbid','AAE');
insert into Employee (Emp_Id,firstName,lastName,salary,Dep_Id,AdCode) values (1,'john' , 'samo' , 1000 , (select DepId from Department where Dep_Name = 'IT'),(select code from address where street = 'AAA'));
insert into Employee (Emp_Id,firstName,lastName,salary,Dep_Id,AdCode) values (2,'mark' , 'wol' , 2000 , (select DepId from Department where Dep_Name = 'IT'),(select code from address where street = 'AAB'));
insert into Employee (Emp_Id,firstName,lastName,salary,Dep_Id,AdCode) values (3,'ahmad' , 'moh' , 1100 , (select DepId from Department where Dep_Name = 'IT'),(select code from address where street = 'AAC'));
insert into Employee (Emp_Id,firstName,lastName,salary,Dep_Id,AdCode) values (4,'maher' , 'imk' , 1700 , (select DepId from Department where Dep_Name = 'CS'),(select code from address where street = 'AAD'));
insert into Employee (Emp_Id,firstName,lastName,salary,Dep_Id,AdCode) values (5,'ali' , 'geh' , 1200 , (select DepId from Department where Dep_Name = 'CS'),(select code from address where street = 'AAE'));
insert into contact_info values ('john@gmail.com',0785602200, (select Emp_Id from Employee where salary = 1000));
insert into contact_info values ('mark@gmail.com',0785602201, (select Emp_Id from Employee where salary = 2000));
insert into contact_info values ('ahmad@gmail.com',0785602202, (select Emp_Id from Employee where salary = 1100));
insert into contact_info values ('maher@gmail.com',0785602203, (select Emp_Id from Employee where salary = 1700));
insert into contact_info values ('ali@gmail.com',0785602204, (select Emp_Id from Employee where salary = 1200));
-- trigger :
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER add_rec
AFTER INSERT
ON Department
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
Empl_id NUMBER;
BEGIN
INSERT INTO address(code,city,street)
VALUES(:NEW.code, :NEW.city, :NEW.street)
INSERT INTO contact_info(email, phone, EmpId)
VALUES(:NEW.email, :NEW.phone, :NEW.EmpId)
INSERT INTO Employee(Emp_Id,firstName,lastName,salary,Dep_Id,AdCode)
VALUES(:NEW.Emp_Id, :NEW.firstName, :NEW.lastName, :NEW.salary, :NEW.lastName, :NEW.Dep_Id, :NEW.AdCode)
END;
-- Package :
set serveroutput on;
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE emp_dept AS
TYPE EmpDept IS RECORD (employee_id number , last_name varchar2(25) , department_id number);
CURSOR dept_employees RETURN EmpDept;
PROCEDURE department_employee;
END emp_dept;
/
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY emp_dept AS
CURSOR dept_employees RETURN EmpDept is (select employee_id , last_name , d.department_id from Employee e join Department d on e.department_id = d.department_id);
rec EmpDept; 
PROCEDURE department_employee
is 
begin
open dept_employees;
loop
fetch dept_employees into rec;
exit when dept_employees%notfound;
dbms_output.put_line(rpad(rec.employee_id,5,' ') ||rpad(rec.last_name,12,' ') || rec.department_id);
end loop;
end;
END emp_dept;
/
execute EMP_DEPT.DEPARTMENT_EMPLOYEE;
```

Answer (score 0):

As of package, when you fix errors (wrong column names), it compiles and returns result:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE emp_dept AS
  2      TYPE empdept IS RECORD (
  3          employee_id   NUMBER,
  4          last_name     VARCHAR2(25),
  5          department_id NUMBER
  6      );
  7      CURSOR dept_employees RETURN empdept;
  8      PROCEDURE department_employee;
  9
 10  END emp_dept;
 11  /

Package created.

SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY emp_dept AS
  2
  3      CURSOR dept_employees RETURN empdept IS
  4      ( SELECT
  5          emp_id,
  6          lastname,
  7          d.depid
  8      FROM
  9               employee e
 10          JOIN department d ON e.dep_id = d.depid
 11      );
 12
 13      rec empdept;
 14
 15      PROCEDURE department_employee IS
 16      BEGIN
 17          OPEN dept_employees;
 18          LOOP
 19              FETCH dept_employees INTO rec;
 20              EXIT WHEN dept_employees%notfound;
 21              dbms_output.put_line(rpad(rec.employee_id, 5, ' ')
 22                                   || rpad(rec.last_name, 12, ' ')
 23                                   || rec.department_id);
 24
 25          END LOOP;
 26
 27      END;
 28
 29  END emp_dept;
 30  /

Package body created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> EXECUTE emp_dept.department_employee;
1    samo        1
2    wol         1
3    moh         1
4    imk         2
5    geh         2

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

---

As of trigger: that question/requirement doesn't make any sense. How would you enter rows into all those tables, based on 3 columns you enter into the  `department` table? You just don't have any values to insert ... From my point of view, either you misinterpreted the problem, or it can't be done as you described it.